# PHP Mailer if else

Tags: php

I am trying to send a different email to users after the confirmation of registration. One will be for admin users and the other text will be for basic users.  I wrote and if else statement based on queried data but its sending both emails to both types of users.  Any idea what is wrong?

```
function SendBusWelcomeEmail(&$user_rec)
    {
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT business FROM users")
               or die(mysql_error());


if($result='a') {
        $mailer = new PHPMailer();

        $mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

        $mailer->AddAddress($user_rec['email'],$user_rec['name']);

        $mailer->Subject = "Welcome to ".$this->sitename;

        $mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();        

        $mailer->Body ="Thank You ".$user_rec['name']." for joining xxx, \r\n\r\n".
        "We are a brand new business with big ambitions. Our mission is to help the development of your skills \r\n".

        "\r\n".
        "Regards,\r\n".
        "Webmaster\r\n".
        $this->sitename;
}
        if(!$mailer->Send())
        {
            $this->HandleError("Failed sending user welcome email.");
            return false;
        }
        else{
        $mailer = new PHPMailer();

        $mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

        $mailer->AddAddress($user_rec['email'],$user_rec['name']);

        $mailer->Subject = "Welcome to ".$this->sitename;

        $mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();        

        $mailer->Body ="Hello ".$user_rec['name']."\r\n\r\n".
        "Welcome! Your registration  with ".$this->sitename." is completed.\r\n".
        "\r\n".
        "Regards,\r\n".
        "Webmaster\r\n".
        $this->sitename;

        if(!$mailer->Send())
        {
            $this->HandleError("Failed sending user welcome email.");
            return false;
        }
}
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your condtion it should be `==` rather than `=`.

So change

```
if($result = 'a')
```

to

```
if($result == 'a')
```

**Note**: You are not fetching the record. And It seems that your query must contain a where condition to get business type of user. Not sure though.

**Tip**: Why don't you get your common code out of the both condition & just change the mail body content depending on the condition.

Comment: if I change that I then get an error at this line if(!$mailer->Send()).  says that the send() function not specified.

Comment: Take that if condition in your above if statement. Just after `$this->sitename;` & before `}`.

Answer (score 2):

after this line

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT business FROM users") or die(mysql_error());
```

use for fetching the result.

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```